# Reformat SQL Server Table Column Names and Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table stored in a SQL Server database that contains user ID, Product Name and values by week stored in columns. The column names for the weeks are named like this "trx_2015#08#07" and the value for that week is stored in each column:

```
UserId, ProductName, trx_2015#08#07, trx_2015#08#014, trx_2015#08#21
```

I would like to clean up those column names (I can't alter the table) to just be the week value (2015-08-07) then pivot the data to be in this format:

```
userID, ProductName, Week, Value
```

Any thoughts on the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is there (possibly) an unlimited number of columns for the week's data? I.e. your columns start at `20150807` but could there be columns all the way up to `20171225` (or further)?

Comment: How will you change the column name without altering the table? Do you plan to create a view? Echoing previous question, how many columns are there?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47382716/transform-data-in-sql-server/47384320#47384320). Just change the column names and data types.

Comment: Yes, a new column gets added weekly. I don't need to re-name the column just alter in the query. This is to pull into Tableau.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server provides a method for manipulating the data as you would like to with the use of the [`UNPIVOT` relational operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot). Below is an example of how to accomplish this in addition to dynamically obtaining the column names (ideally, we would not want to update the query every time a column is added).

### Schema/Data Setup for Answer

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  UserId INT,
  ProductName NVARCHAR(1000),
  [trx_2015#08#07] INT,
  [trx_2015#08#014] INT,
  [trx_2015#08#21] INT
);

INSERT INTO tbl(UserId, ProductName, [trx_2015#08#07], [trx_2015#08#014], [trx_2015#08#21])
VALUES (1, 'Product #1', 123, 456, 789);
```

### Dynamically obtaining `trx` column names

We will need an aggregate concatenation of the `trx` colmn names to pass to the `UNPIVOT` relational overator's `IN` clause.

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'tbl'
    AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'trx_%'
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
```

### Building the query

Ultimately, we would like the query to look like this:

```
SELECT UserId, ProductName, Value, trx 
FROM tbl 
  UNPIVOT(
    Value FOR trx IN ([trx_2015#08#014],[trx_2015#08#07],[trx_2015#08#21])
  ) AS unpvt
```

The query must be built dynamically in SQL because the `IN` clause here cannot accept a result set.

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQLString = CONCAT(
  'SELECT UserId, ProductName, Value, trx FROM tbl UNPIVOT(Value FOR trx IN (', 
  (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = 'tbl'
    AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'trx_%'
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')), 
  ')) AS unpvt'
);

EXEC(@SQLString);
```

**Result Set:**

```
UserId  ProductName Value   trx
1       Product #1  456     trx_2015#08#014
1       Product #1  123     trx_2015#08#07
1       Product #1  789     trx_2015#08#21
```